# image(path only) insertion in database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to insert image(path only) to database.I have written this code but here every time the default.png(path only) is inserted.I want to insert other images also.

```
$maxId = $this->user_master_m->get_max_product_id();
                    $new_file = "defualt.png";
                    if ($_FILES["image"]['name'] != "") {
                        $file_name = $_FILES["image"]['name'];
                        $file_name_rename = 'P-' . $maxId->id;
                        $explode = explode('.', $file_name);
                        if (count($explode) >= 2) {

                            $new_file = $file_name_rename . '.' . $explode[1];
                            $config['upload_path'] = "./uploads/images";
                            $config['allowed_types'] = "gif|jpg|png";
                            $config['file_name'] = $new_file;
                            $config['max_size'] = '1024';
                            $config['max_width'] = '3000';
                            $config['max_height'] = '3000';
                            $array['product_image'] = $new_file;
                            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                            if (!$this->upload->do_upload("image")) {
                                $this->data["image"] = $this->upload->display_errors();
                                $this->data["subview"] = "admin_view/product_form_view";
                                $this->load->view('_layout_main', $this->data);
                            } else {
                                $data = array("upload_data" => $this->upload->data());
                                $this->user_master_m->add_product_m($array);

                            }
                        } else {
                            $this->data["image"] = "Invalid file";
                            $this->data["subview"] = "admin_view/product_form_view";
                            $this->load->view('_layout_main', $this->data);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $array["product_image"] = $new_file;
                        $this->user_master_m->add_product_m($array);
                    }
```

Comment: First you check var_dump($_FILES["image"]['name']) and add the result

Comment: Pls check your form is form_open_multipart() otherwise u can not access $_FILES

Comment: thank for your answers......

Answer (score 0):

Try to print $_FILES by

`print_r($_FILES);`

to check whether you are getting the image properly or not.